How to Access Bluetooth (BLE) Devices in a Dockerized Flask App on Windows Using WSL2?
I'm trying to dockerize a Flask app that interacts with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices on my Windows 11 machine using WSL2 (Ubuntu).
What I've Done:

Set Up WSL2 and Docker Desktop:


Installed Ubuntu on WSL2.
Installed Docker Desktop with WSL2 integration.


Installed usbipd-win to Attach USB Bluetooth Dongle:


Ran usbipd list and found my USB Bluetooth dongle (BUSID 2-1).
Attached it to WSL2:

usbipd attach --busid 2-1 --wsl Ubuntu

Verified Device in WSL2:


lsusb shows the Bluetooth dongle:

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

Enabled Systemd and Installed Bluetooth Packages:


Edited /etc/wsl.conf to enable systemd.
Installed bluetooth, bluez, etc.


Attempted to Start Bluetooth Service:

sudo systemctl start bluetooth
Error:
Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).

Checked for Bluetooth Directory:

ls /sys/class/bluetooth
Result:
No such file or directory

Tried Using bluetoothctl and hciconfig:


Both report errors indicating no Bluetooth hardware is found.

My Problem:

I can't get the Bluetooth service to recognize the USB Bluetooth dongle in WSL2.
As a result, my Dockerized Flask app can't access BLE devices.

Question:

How can I enable BLE access in my Dockerized Flask app running in WSL2 on Windows?
Is there a way to get the Bluetooth service to recognize the dongle?
Are there alternative approaches to access BLE devices from Docker in this setup?


The Windows WSL2 vanilla kernel doesn't support Bluetooth out of the box. You will need to compile your own kernel with Bluetooth enabled.
If the kernel does support Bluetooth, you will find the information in the boot log file (dmesg | grep Bluetooth).
something like:
...
[    3.020247] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    4.103101] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    4.103143] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.103151] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.103154] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.103160] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.251575] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.251579] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.251589] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.309729] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    4.309745] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.309747] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    4.554945] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
...

